# How to confirm/validate a users real-life actions in an app

Tags: swift, verification, confirmation, verify, anti-cheat

I have an idea for an app that rewards users for completing real-life actions (things like recycling, eating healthy .etc) but I want to avoid having a button on every action saying "I did it" because then some users will just click all the buttons to get the rewards.

I have tried searching Stack Overflow for things like "confirming a users actions" and have not turned up any promising results.

Some examples of actions I would like to try and confirm if possible are:

- recycling
- certain food items the user buys (barcode scanner maybe?)
- donations to thrift shops (goodwill .etc)
- users energy bills/use

I understand that some of these may need to be trust-based (I.e. With a "I'm done" button) but I would like to minimize the use of this as much as possible to prevent users from cheating the system. Does anyone know of some reliable ways to verify that the user has completed the tasks before offering rewards?

Comment: why so many close votes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to look at the sensors that are available to you on the device. Honestly I can't see a way to do many of the things you suggested. Location based actions may be a good route. Checking in within 1Km of the gym or thrift store for example.

I heard about an app (i forget the name) where you would program in what exercise you are trying to do then the gyro and accelerometer in the phone would determine if you are performing the exercise correctly and verifying how many times you did it.

Comment: you know of an easy way to check if the user is near a thrift store for example?

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial on MapKit. http://www.thorntech.com/2016/01/how-to-search-for-location-using-apples-mapkit/  MKLocalSearch should be what you are looking for. Other companies like MapQuest or Google may have more robust searching but MapKit is the apple service

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: is there any way to search for categories of places instead of the actual place with `MapKit`?

Comment: It looks like MapKit uses a class MKMapItem which has info about locations but it doesn't have what you need. The Google Maps API for iOS has a class GMSPlace which seems to have what you need.  https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table1

Comment: Hmm. On maps.google.com Goodwill is listed as a donations store but I don't see that type listed in the link I gave you, You will have to look at the types of thrift stores you are thinking of and see what classification they are given.

Comment: and theres nothing like this for `MapKit`? not even anything remotely similar? I know the built-in apple maps app allows you to sort by place category such as shopping or entertainment... could i use that?

Comment: It doesn't look like that info is returned when performing a search. Seems limited to the google maps API.